# How can i perform the "st_" queries in oracle?

Tags: oracle, spatial

I have some spatial queries. First of all, I created the tables and inserted the values successfully.But i could not execute the queries. 
What should i do? Here's the query:

`select name, ST_Area(koordinat) as alan 
from poligonbolge;`

When i tried this query, i took an error;

```
ORA-00904: "ST_AREA": geçersiz belirleyici
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 14
```

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select name, sde.st_area(koordinat) as alan from poligonbolge;
```

For more example try following link.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/st_area.htm

Comment: Unfortunately,it didn't work. I tried the queries on the link but they didn't work, too.

Comment: I think I found:

`select name, SDO_GEOM.SDO_Area(koordinat,0.005) as alan 
from poligonbolge;`

worked.But now; i could not execute that query:

`select b.name, SUM(nufus) as toplamNufus, AVG(isiort) as sıcaklıkOrt, count(*) as sehirSayısı
from noktasehir s, poligonbolge b
where sdo_geom.sdo_intersection(s.koordinat,b.koordinat,0.005)='t'
order by toplamNufus DESC;`

I have no idea about "0.005". I found from the web. It works on another queries. (length,area etc.)